# Cluster points with MapKit to only show first or last drawn pin when zoomed out? (instead of stacking?)

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

So I'm trying to get map points within MapKit to cluster into the first or last dropped pin in that area when the user zoomed out instead of just having them stack up. When the user zooms back in, they're dropped again.

Is there a way to do this that's practical or must it be done on the server-side live? I don't see why it couldn't be done on the client, except if it were too resource intensive for iOS.

Comment: do u want to show all pins in mapview?

Comment: Yes, but only if they're not overlapping each other... to create better performance at a lesser zoom level. Otherwise, if you zoom into an area, it should show them when more detail is required.

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047691/iphone-map-kit-cluster-pinpoints